# Use FFMpeg to get middle frame of a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm wondering how to use FFMpeg to grap the middle frame of a video. I've already written the C# to grab a frame at a certain time (ie pull one frame at second 3). But I've yet to figure out how to find the middle of video using the FFMpeg commands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be simplified, but here's some old PHP code I had lying around that should do the trick. (Add the location to ffmpeg if it's not in your path)

```
$output = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i {$path}");
preg_match('/Duration: ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([^ ,])+/', $output, $matches);
$time = str_replace("Duration: ", "", $matches[0]);
$time_breakdown = explode(":", $time);
$total_seconds = round(($time_breakdown[0]*60*60) + ($time_breakdown[1]*60) + $time_breakdown[2]);
shell_exec("ffmpeg -y  -i {$path} -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -ss " . ($total_seconds / 2) . " -s {$w}x{$h} {$output_filename}");
```

Comment: @Derek Gathright Please give me basic detail to start working with ffmpeg. Please have a look my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071408/how-to-get-frames-of-video-file-in-android).

Answer (score 9):

With simple shell scripting you can use `ffprobe` to get a machine readable duration output, `bc` to calculate the half point, and `ffmpeg` to make the frame:

```
input=input.mp4; ffmpeg -ss "$(bc -l <<< "$(ffprobe -loglevel error -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration "$input")*0.5")" -i "$input" -frames:v 1 half.png
```

This eliminates any need for PHP, `echo`, `awk`, `tr`, `grep`, `sed`, etc.

Comment: On Windows/Cygwin I had to do an ugly kludge text processing of the output of eval / ffprobe to eliminate a windows newline from the end of $format_duration:

`eval "$(ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -show_entries format=duration tmp.mp4)"`

`echo $format_duration > tmp.txt`

`echo /2 >> tmp.txt`

`dos2unix tmp.txt`

format_duration=``tr -d '\n' < tmp.txt``

If someone knows a more elegant means of using $format_duration on Windows, I'd be glad to know it.

Comment: There's a set of backticks surrounding the variable assignment after format_duration in the last part of my comment (which is eliminated here by markdown parsing).

Comment: Wish I could have upvoted more. Thanks for the simple two-liner.

Comment: If the video is less than two seconds long, `bc` returns a number without the leading zero, e.g. `.987`, which causes an error: `Invalid duration specification for ss: .987`. It seems that additional leading zero is ok for `ss`, so I'm adding a `0` here: `... -ss 0"$(bc ...`. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197896/how-to-show-zero-before-decimal-point-in-bc

Answer (score 4):

FFmpeg helps you get the framerate and the length of the video, so you can multiply one by the other and divide by 2 to get the number of the middle frame.

ie for a 30 seconds video running at 15 frames per second : 30 * 15 = 450 / 2 = 225, meaning you need to grab the 225th frame.

Answer (score -1):

This bash command works like a charm (tested):

```
avconv -i 'in.mpg' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 420x300 -ss avconv -i in.mpg 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d , | awk -F ':' '{print ($3+$2*60+$1*3600)/2}' out.jpg
```