# How to get the frame from video file in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The [MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29) always returns same frames when ever call.
Have a look my code

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> getFrames(String path){
    try {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        bArray.clear();
        MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mRetriever.setDataSource(getDataSource(path));

        for (int i = 3000; i <60000; i=i+5000) {
            bArray.add(mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));

        }

        return bArray;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        return null;

    }
}
```

This method always return same frames

Comment: That's behaviour you can expect, as per documentation: *"This method finds a representative frame close to the given time position by considering the given option **if possible**, and returns it as a bitmap. Returns: A Bitmap containing a representative video frame, which can be null, if such a frame cannot be retrieved."*

Comment: @MH. thank for reply how can i get the frames from video file. Have a Look my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071408/how-to-get-frames-of-video-file-in-android)

Comment: After 3 yrs, m still trying to find it hard for the solution...any one knows about the solution???

Comment: Same here after 2 yrs more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to have to use something like FFMPEG to fetch the frames.

You will have to use the NDK, and compile FFMPEG for Android; unfortunately it's not going to be very easy.

A couple of starting points:

http://ffmpeg.org/

[ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: "ffmpeg and Android.mk")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk)

Good luck!

Comment: is there any chance to do same if video is on server

Answer (score 11):

I don't know how long is your video, but the time to use in the long var as the time for `getTimeAtFrame` must be expressed in **MICRO** seconds

ex: a video of 1 second have 1000000 USeconds, if use a very short period (like you) you must very lucky for retrieve the first frame only that you video have!!!

Comment: I've had this problem too and I'm definitely sure that it has nothing to do with the time interval that is used. And the example from the OP is using micro seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Léon Pelletier is right. The problem is that [MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29) could only extract key frames from video at **second level**. For example, if a video has about 4 seconds, you can get only 4 
 or 5 different frames. To get all video frames, please refer to [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html).

Comment: I think this should  not post as an answer. You should post it as comment.

Comment: My original answer did respond the same-frame question, and I modified it so it responds the title too.