# How to get a list of key frames (sync frames) time stamps for a video file in Android?

Tags: android, video

Is there any API which can give me the list of time stamps of the key frames for the given video file in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/

> The isoparser API can read and write the MP4 file structure. It is a low level tool dealing with the so called boxes but it is as well as dealing with structure like tracks and movies.

Nice API and ways much faster than ffmpeg behemoth

Comment: yes but isoparser doesn't contains decoder/encoder to create bitmap's from the boxes's mdat section

Comment: @Nativ That was not the question.

Comment: Lol I asked it at 2013

Answer (score 10):

For an elegant solution, it seems as if you'd need to use ffmpeg for android to achieve this. Someone else tried it that way: [How to get the frame from video file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188938/how-to-get-the-frame-from-video-file-in-android) ; and was suggested to use ffmpeg.

I checked the reference manual, but could only find a way to get a keyframe itself (without timestamp) relative to a given position in time using the MediaMetadataRetriever() as explained here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#extractMetadata%28int%29

If you don't want to use ffmpeg you could try the following:

```
private ArrayList<int> getKeyFrameTimestamps(String filename) {
  ArrayList<int> timeStamps = new ArrayList<int>();

  try {
    MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mRetriever.setDataSource(getDataSource(filename));
    mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);

    Bitmap lastFame = mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_NEXT_SYNC);
    result.add(0);

    for(int time=1; frame ; ++time) {
      Bitmap frame = mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(time, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
      if (frame && !frame.sameAs(lastFrame)) {
        result.add(time);
        lastFrame = frame;
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {  /* TODO: HANDLE THIS */ }

  return timeStamps;
}
```

This is of course not very elegant, but would probably work without hassle to install ffmpeg... It's probably also quite slow (I don't know). But maybe it's just what you need.

PS: An ffmpeg tutorial that fits your problem can be found here: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial07.html

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your efforts, but I have already tried this solution and it works damn slow and delivers strange results. I will investigate further on (e.g. ffmpeg / ffprobe) and keep this thread updated.

Comment: Thats what I've expected. An idea to speed this up a bit is trying `time += lastdistance;` Where you use set `lastdistance = lastFrameTime - time;` if a keyframe is found, check if `lastFrameTime + lastdistance - 1` is still the last frame. If so, go on... else use the "slow search" to find the next frame

Comment: cross compile ffmpeg onto android. use ffprobe command with -show_frames option to get the list of I pictures. This should work for all types of videos and is quite fast. Check it out on the PC first. [If you have installed ffmpeg, you should have ffprobe as well]. You will get all the information you need. There is -show_packets which is even faster and can prove sufficient if all you want to know is reference vs non reference frames.

Answer (score 2):

4.1+ - faster than mp4parser because done in native underneath and the code is cleaner

mp4parser you have to calculate the timestamps from the getsyncsamples + getsampledurations which is also annoying and they don't match up with ffprobe. this gets accurate results

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(getVideoPath());

int trackindex = MediaExtractorUtil.selectVideoTrack(extractor);
extractor.selectTrack(trackindex);

while (extractor.getSampleTime() != -1) {
    long sampleTime = extractor.getSampleTime();

    // check not really necessary but JIC
    if ((extractor.getSampleFlags() & MediaExtractor.SAMPLE_FLAG_SYNC) > 0) {
        mKeyframeTimestampsMS.add(sampleTime / 1000);
    }

    extractor.seekTo(sampleTime + 1, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_NEXT_SYNC);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'd check that as soon as i get back to this project

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@ryan gordon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609466/437492). `seekTo` may seek to the same frame, even when `SEEK_TO_NEXT_SYNC` is specified. To avoid this, you can terminate once frames start repeating.

For example:

```
    private fun getSyncFrameTimestamps(source: MediaExtractor): List<Long> {
        val result = mutableListOf<Long>()

        var lastSampleTime = -1L
        var sampleTime = source.sampleTime

        while (sampleTime >= 0L && sampleTime != lastSampleTime) {
            if (source.sampleFlags and MediaExtractor.SAMPLE_FLAG_SYNC != 0) {
                result.add(sampleTime)
            }
            source.seekTo(sampleTime + 1L, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_NEXT_SYNC)
            lastSampleTime = sampleTime
            sampleTime = source.sampleTime
        }

        return result
    }
```

Note that before calling this, `source` should have the data source set, and video track selected.

Answer (score -1):

Using [MediaExtractor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html), you can have all key(sync)frames times and/or any specific keyframe at any desired time . +some more useful data.

Then by MediaMetadataRetriever -> getFrameAtTime you can get frame Bitmaps.

here is a sample code to use MediaExtractor:

```
    mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor() ;
    mediaExtractor.setDataSource(mediaPath);
    int numTracks = mediaExtractor.getTrackCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i) {
        MediaFormat format = mediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        if ( mime.startsWith("video") ) {
            mediaExtractor.selectTrack(i);
        }
        Log.i( "LOG_Extractor" , "track "+i+" "+mime );
    }

    currentTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    mediaExtractor.seekTo( (long)currentTime*1000 , MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC );
    previousKeyFrameTimeMilis = mediaExtractor.getSampleTime() /1000 ;
```