# I want to display multiple video in listview using video but not able to do this

Tags: android

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    public ArrayList<String> videoList;
    public CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        videoList = new ArrayList<String>();
        videoList.add("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zgfi7wnGZlE");
        videoList.add("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zgfi7wnGZlE");
        videoList.add("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zgfi7wnGZlE");
        videoList.add("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdlWPL53PvQ#sthash.fW5EtDFb.dpuf");
        Log.d("size of videoList:",""+ videoList.size());
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, videoList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> videoList;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.videoList = videoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return videoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return videoList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

              VideoView video = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
             video.setVideoPath(videoList.get(position));
             video.start();
             return convertView;
        }

    }    
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_raw.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't get video and no any error display in logcat thenb what is the issue?
I added Internet permission in manifest is any or permission or any other settting is required?

Comment: please http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example

Comment: @nidhi i thing it will take more loading becuse every item view try to dowload video. but best way to display in listview is take a thumb image and display image over there

Answer (score 1):

I think we should not put video view directly in the list, Since each and every view in list are redrawn or invalidated lot of times and if any video is being played and watched by user and he accidentally scrolls it off the screen , Android OS will free up that memory and hence again video will be played from Start. **Video.start() will be called again and again**

**Best Solution** is to provide a thumbnail image of any frame of video . **Replace Video view with image view** and on click of it open a new screen where put a video view and play on to it.

Comment: please give me link for this type of code to refer.

Comment: By  following link you can get a frame of a video as a bitmap. Set it to your image view.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071408/how-to-get-frames-of-video-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `VideoURI` instead of `VideoPath` and check again,

```
VideoView video = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
video.setMediaController(mediaController);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoList.get(position)));
video.start();
```

**UPDATE:** If you are planning to use video's from YouTube only then the best way would be using the official YouTube API. Check here,

[Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

[How to Play YouTube Video in Android App](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/)

Comment: I have added this code instead of setting videopath I have set videouri still video is not displaying in my listview I am getting blank listview.