# How to do feeding on Android Java?

Tags: java, android, feed

I'll create a YouTube channel and planning to do an app for my channel. The thing is on my mind, when I upload a new video, I'll put the new video's link in a text on my server, then the app will read the new video is uploaded and fetch link (when the app launched) and will add new videoview to top of old ones.

Like official YouTube app. You know, when a new video uploaded, it comes out automatically.

Thanks for your future helps.

Comment: If you're looking to send push notifications, [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) will be a good place to start

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Titus but this is not what I want. I could explain brighter if you couldn't get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a custom RecyclerView and follow this [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/) on how to embed YouTube videos in an android app. If you plan on caching the old YouTube URLs you can ping the database every time they open the app and grab all the new URLs that have been added to your database since the latest cached URL.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to get the text from server?Are you using POST method or JSON?
In any case once you get the link it's easy.You just have to implement a custom ListView.

Here is link to a article that I found that shows how to do it.

https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.grvqarw83

Here is another article which shows how to integrate youtube with your app.

https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/my-mini-project/multiple-youtube-video-in-recyclerviewlistview-in-android/

Also another question like the one you asked.

[I want to display multiple video in listview using video but not able to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532893/i-want-to-display-multiple-video-in-listview-using-video-but-not-able-to-do-this)

Comment: I'm not sure about what I'll use. I don't know any of them. I can explain you brighter like this; I'll create an xml or maybe a txt on my server, it'll has it's own keys like, "<videourl=youtu.be/something title="My new video>" when I add new string like this when new video uploded, the app will load the new video at the list.

Comment: Getting URL and storing it into you local database is pretty straightforward.You can write a script that gives JSON response. After you have got all of you links in to the local SQLite database of your app,you can use any of the above links to create a beautiful UI.