# To convert the extension of a file to the different directory by a ffmpeg command

Tags: unix, ffmpeg, centos6, plesk

The command below is to convert from mp4 file to jpg file with the same file name in the same directory, .../httpdocs/save/.

```
[root@server-xxxxx-x ~]# for i in `find /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/save/ -type f -name "*.mp4"`; do ffmpeg -i $i `echo $i | sed -En "s/.mp4$/.jpg/p"`; done
```

Now, I need to convert from, .../httpdocs/save/ to the different directory, .../httpdocs/file/, how should I change the command above?  I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out.


ffmpeg version 2.2.2

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/1109017) and simply add the directory name to the output. Make sure to run the command from the directory containing the inputs.

Comment: Thanks, LordNeckbeard, I've tried every possible way, but I cann't figure out where exactly in the command line I should add the second directory which is "/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/file/".

Comment: You don't need to. Just run the command from `/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/file/` as the current directory (run `cd /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/file/` then run the command).

Comment: Thanks, LordNeckbeard, I have Two question. I need to convert from xxxxxx_xxxxxxx.mp4 in .../save/ to xxxxxx_xxxxxxx.jpg file in .../file/. 
How can I use PHP function, shell_exec('xxxxxx') for this case, "run cd and then run the command"?

Comment: Sorry, but I know nothing of PHP.

Comment: Sorry, LordNeckbeard, I need to convert from xxxxxx_xxxxxxx.mp4 in .../save/ to xxxxxx_xxxxxxx.jpg file in .../file/. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple method is to execute the command from the directory containing the input files:

```
cd "/path/to/inputs" && for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -frames:v 1 "/path/to/outputs/${i%.*}.jpg"; done
```

Or you could use `basename` if you want to put the full path in the *for loop*:

```
for i in /path/to/inputs/*.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -frames:v 1 "/path/to/outputs/$(basename "$i" .mp4).jpg"; done
```

...but it is less efficient than only using [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

```
for i in /path/to/inputs/*.mp4; do filepath="${i##*/}"; ffmpeg -i "$i" -frames:v 1 "/path/to/outputs/${filepath%.*}.jpg"; done
```

Other relevant questions:

- [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784661/1109017)
- [Use ffmpeg to get middle frame of a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066638)
- [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from an H264 video file with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/1109017)

Comment: Thanks,LordNeckbeard, I really appreciate your support. The second one from the top is working as perfectly as I could possibly expect in my environment. I also appreciate the list of relevant questions. Thank you for your time and effort on this thread.