# How to replace the text in the filename and move the file to different directory

Tags: bash, for-loop, replace, ffmpeg

I'm a newbie to this bash scripting and I'm writing a script with ffmpeg to help my production more efficient. I think I put two questions at once and hope it won't be confused:

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.mov
do
  ffmpeg  -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 100M -ss 00:00:10.00 -i "$file" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 - 
  c:a aac_at -ab 256k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict -2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -r 24000/1001 
  -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -partitions 
  partb8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+parti8x8 -b-pyramid 1 -weightb 1 -8x8dct 1 -fast-pskip 1 - 
  direct-pred 1 -coder ac -trellis 1 -motion-est hex -subq 6 -me_range 16 -bf 3 -b_strategy 1 
  -sc_threshold 40 -keyint_min 24 -g 48 -qmin 3 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -metadata creation_time=now 
  -sn -t 00:01:00.02 -y "${file%.*}_H264_1080".mov
done
```

Basically what I'm tyring to do is taking a "Movie_ProRes_1080.mov" file and make it as a H264 and rename it as "Movie_H264_1080.mov". The way I work around is Export the file as "Movie" and let it added behind which is really not what I want because I need to export another file to fit this purpose. The main goal is I can use the "Movie_ProRes_1080.mov" convert it to "Movie_H264_1080".

Also, from the script, it rendered out to the same location. Would it be possible to render to a different directory? Like source at /Users/editor/source, but render out at /Users/editor/output.

Comment: The script can specify the folder in the output file name: "/users/editor/output/${file%.*}_H264_1080".mov"

Comment: dash-o Thank you for the help. I tried it, but  it shows No such file or directory.

Comment: You need to slightly change your parameter expansion. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.mov
do
  ffmpeg -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 100M -ss 00:00:10.00 -i "$file" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 \
  -c:a aac_at -ab 256k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -r 24000/1001 \ 
  -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -metadata creation_time=now \
  -sn -t 00:01:00.02 "output/${file%%_*}_H264_1080.mov"
done
```

- If you execute this in `/Users/editor/source` you can simply add the output directory name to the output file. If you want to execute this from any arbitrary location then see some [additional examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213477/to-convert-the-extension-of-a-file-to-the-different-directory-by-a-ffmpeg-comman/49247055#49247055) utilizing more [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) or `basename`.
- No need for declaring so many x264 options when you can just use `-preset` alone to deal with them. That's what `-preset` was made for. So you can remove everything between and including `-partitions` to `-qdiff`. `-strict -2` can be removed too because you are not using an experimental component.

Comment: Cool! The output is working! Thank you so much llogan. I will try to work on -preset before, need a little bit of research. How about the replace the filename text? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @HugoShih It should already deal with the requested name change.