# How to divide a time duration in half

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I'm trying to find the midpoint of a video, in other words divide the total length by `2`. `ffmpeg` gives time in format `HOURS:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS`, so ignoring microseconds, how could I get the half way point? I've tried dividing each number (`hours/minutes/seconds`) by `2` but this fails in the case of `0:01:00`, for example.

Comment: Can you show some code? What have you tried?

Comment: @mkopriva you caught me before I could properly format my answer :)

Comment: @KellyFlet: You should properly format your question before posting it.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? My question was clear enough for @icza to provide a clear and concise answer without any further clarification. I provided an answer to my own question, so it's not as if I didn't try anything (as is often the complaint) and thought I would not clutter the question with all the different things I tried; instead, keeping it simple. Of course, my answer was not the most succinct, which is why the community is here to provide better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be much simpler (and maybe even faster) if we use the parsing and formatting logic provided by the [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package.

```
func getDividedTime(times string, n int) (string, error) {
    t, err := time.Parse("15:04:05.000000", times)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    d := t.Sub(time.Time{}) / time.Duration(n)
    return time.Time{}.Add(d).Format("15:04:05"), nil
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3HfUqRvwMpj). The weakness of this solution is that it "rejects" inputs having `hours > 23`.

Comment: I also thought of this first but I wouldn't like to have this upper bound of 24 hours in a timer implementation. Check [this](https://play.golang.org/p/JhoAAc49X1f) one out!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid parsing the stderr output of `ffmpeg` to get duration (that's what I'm assuming you're doing): it's not meant for machine parsing and is prone to breakage. That's what `ffprobe` is for and you won't have to perform additional processing to isolate the duration.

You can use `ffprobe` to get duration in seconds which is much easier to divide:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

Example result:

```
48.012000
```

Then use your favorite function or tool to divide by 2. ([Example using `bc` in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066638/use-ffmpeg-to-get-middle-frame-of-a-video/35026487#35026487).)

If you require `HOURS:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS` then add the `-sexagesimal` option.

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler solution that uses `Duration` and not `Time`. It allows parsing of hours `> 24`. This is usually desired when dealing with timers or in your case, video duration!

```golang
func getDividedTime(st string, div int) string {
    var h, m, s int
    fmt.Sscanf(st, "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s)
    seconds := (h*60*60 + m*60 + s) / div
    d := time.Duration(int64(seconds) * int64(1e9))
    hh, mm, ss := int(d.Hours()), int(d.Minutes()), int(d.Seconds())
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", hh, mm-(hh*60), ss-(mm*60))
}
```

Try it in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JhoAAc49X1f)! Feel free to check for invalid input errors returned by `fmt.Sscanf()`!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to:

1. **Convert everything to seconds**
2. **Divide by 2**
3. **Convert back to hours:minutes:seconds**

(and do some formatting for `ffmpeg`).
Also note that this answer can be generalized to dividing by `n`, instead of just halving.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

// ffmpeg uses the format HOURS:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS
func getDividedTime(time string, n int) string {
    times := strings.Split(time, ":")

    // get rid of microseconds
    times[2] = strings.Split(times[2], ".")[0]

    // conversions
    minutesToSeconds := 60
    hoursToSeconds := 60 * minutesToSeconds

    // convert everything to seconds
    seconds, _ := strconv.Atoi(times[2])
    minutes, _ := strconv.Atoi(times[1])
    hours, _ := strconv.Atoi(times[0])

    secMinutes := minutes * minutesToSeconds
    secHours := hours * hoursToSeconds

    totalSeconds := seconds + secHours + secMinutes
    totalSeconds /= n

    // update time and grab seconds
    newSeconds := totalSeconds % 60
    totalSeconds /= 60

    // update time and grab minutes
    newMinutes := totalSeconds % 60
    totalSeconds /= 60

    newHours := totalSeconds % 3600

    times[0] = strconv.Itoa(newHours)
    times[1] = strconv.Itoa(newMinutes)
    times[2] = strconv.Itoa(newSeconds)

    // zero padding for seconds and minutes (not hours)
    if newMinutes < 10 {
        times[1] = "0" + times[1]
    }
    if newSeconds < 10 {
        times[2] = "0" + times[2]
    }

    dividedTime := strings.Join(times[:], ":")
    return dividedTime 
}

func main() {
    // create some tests
    tables := []struct {
        inputTime   string
        correctTime string
    }{
        {"0:11:28.956000", "0:05:44"},
        {"1:00:00.111999", "0:30:00"},
        {"1:15:00.111999", "0:37:30"},
        {"1:45:00.111999", "0:52:30"},
        {"0:59:00.000000", "0:29:30"},
        {"2:04:22.123151", "1:02:11"},
        {"0:00:00.000000", "0:00:00"},
        {"0:00:03.000000", "0:00:01"},
        {"0:00:04.000000", "0:00:02"},
        {"0:20:00.000000", "0:10:00"},
        {"0:02:00.000000", "0:01:00"},
        {"99:00:00.000000", "49:30:00"},
    }

    // ensure output matches truth values
    for _, table := range tables {
        output := getDividedTime(table.inputTime, 2) // cut time in half
        if output != table.correctTime {
            fmt.Printf("failure: expected: %s, got: %s\n", table.correctTime, output)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *ffmpeg uses the format HOURS:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS* --> only in certain display fields. It will accept decimal seconds in almost every function.