# ffmpeg image watermark on video first half of video on Bottom left and next half of video on Top Right

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, watermark

I was playing with this for several hours, I couldn't make so thought of reaching for help, Can you please help me in framing the ffmpeg command to display the watermark Image on the video, For the Initial half video the watermark should be on the bottom left and for the rest half video the watermark shop be on the right top.

Bottom left: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4`

Top right:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" -codec:a copy output.mp4`

Also, I had a look on this for Timeoverlay [ffmpeg watermark first 30 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160771/ffmpeg-watermark-first-30-second).

How to merge all these and satisfy my requirements as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example the duration of `input.mp4` is 30 seconds. The overlay filter supports the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:enable='lte(t,15)'[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5:enable='gte(t,15)'" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

- To get duration see [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604/). On Linux one method to calculate 50% duration is with `bc`. See example at [Use ffmpeg to get middle frame of a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35026487/)
- Alternative method is to use the [sendcmd filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd), but it is more complicated. See example at [Sendcmd in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600924/).
- See available functions at [FFmpeg Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).